# Refer to deployed jar as maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, war, wildfly-8

folks, please advise. I have a maven project with many maven modules. Those modules are java web applications and one jar, on which those web apps depend and which contains core functionality (let's call it core.jar). I deploy them to stable release of `Wildfly` app server with no problem and everything works fine. However, I noticed that all of my war files contain the same core.jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Could you tell me if it is possible to deploy this core.jar only once and make all war files see it? The only thing I could think of now is to install this core.jar as a jboss module ([like this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html)) and refer to it from manifest file in every web app.
What do you think?

Regards,
Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best solution would be to create JBoss modules. [Here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateAModuleForOracleDatasourceInJBoss711Final) is an example of using OJDBC.
Also, you need to configure a shared lib.
You can use a JBoss specific deployment descriptor, named jboss-app.xml which is to be placed in the META-INF folder of your EAR.
Here's a sample of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 5.0//EN"
"http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd" >
<jboss-app>
    <library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>
</jboss-app>
```

It might be valuable for you to check the [class loading specs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly).

Comment: Great, @aviad, thanks a lot! I was 99% sure that the module is solution, I guess I have to do like you mentioned...